# EntityFramework: To Slice or Not To Slice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I'm just getting started with Entity Framework.  I'm working with a very large, existing database.  I find myself wanting to use EF to create models that are "slices" of the whole database.  These slices corresponde to 1 aspect of the application.  Is that the right way to look at it, or should I try to model the whole database in 1 EDMX?

Let me give you a fictional example:

Suppose that 1 of the many things that this database contains is customer billing information.  I feel like I want to create an EF model that just focuses on the tables that the Customer Billing module needs to interact with.  (so then that model would NOT be used for other modules in the app, rather, those same tables might appear in other small EF models).  This would allow me to leverage EF's conceptual model features (inheritance, etc) to build a view that is correct for Customer Billing, without worrying about that model's effects, on say Customer Support (even though the 2 modules share some tables)

Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds right to me. The point of an Entity Model, after all, is to provide a set of persistence-capable business objects at [a level of abstraction that's appropriate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#ado.netenfrmovw_topic2) to the required business logic.

You should absolutely create entity models that support modules of the application, not models that copy the underlying database schema. As the link above describes, separating logic from persistence is one of the primary purposes of EF.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a slice approach, based of following reasons:

- If you have a massive database with loads of tables, then it would be difficult to manage massive Entity Model.
- It is easier to maintain application / domain specific entities, as entity framework is not a table to entity mapping, you can create custom entities and also combine and split tables across entities.